# synergy ctrl key issue with mac and nomachine

Tags: synergy

I am using following synergy
Setup: 
Server: Ubuntu Linux 
Client: Mac

Everything is working fine apart from keys like ctrl are not working with no-machine. Anyone faced such issue and found solution?

Comment: Are you able to post your Synergy config so we can see what the problem is?